# How can i take backup and Restore in MySQL 5.0

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using MySQL 5.0 as back end with VB.NET as front end(Windows Applicaions). I want to take back up my database. I found one command through net as below.

mysql> mysqldump -u root -p root accounts > accounts.sql

My database name is "accounts". When i am trying to run the above command in mysql> prompt, it gives error. Where i have to run the above command? Kind help needed.Advance Thanks.

Sivakumar.P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use mysql dump in the command line:

mysqldump --user=user --password=password database > database.sql

to restore:

mysql --user=user --password=password database < database.sql

Answer (score 1):

I've never used [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) inside mysql command line. Try using directly on shell/command-line. 
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password. If you omit the password value following the --password or -p option on the command line, you are prompted for one.

What error are you getting? Here is the complete [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) for mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work in Windows though??
I have only used this in Linux, dunno about Windows...

Answer (score 0):

As others said, use mysqldump. Remember not dumping the whole database on a production server, as it will lock all rows during dump.

**binar_E:**
mysqldump exists both for windows and *nix.